# Sql script цикл

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть таблица с юзерами и я выдергиваю оттуда все ID таим образом:

```
SELECT UserID FROM Users
```

теперь для каждого ID из этого списка мне нужно проделать определенные операции (с другими таблицами используя эти ID)

Подскажите, как организовать цикл на SQL

Answer (score 1):

Необязательно зацикливаться на курсорах - есть же еще старый-добрый `while` (для наглядности, пример для того случая, когда поле UserId первичный ключ):

```
declare @id int = 0

while exists(select 1 from Users where UserId >= @id)
begin
    select top(1) @id = UserId from Users where UserId >= @id

    -- необходимые операции

    set @id = @id + 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться [курсором](http://kbss.ru/blog/mssql/55.html)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что вам нужны [соединения](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html).
А циклы - это процедурный подход, которого следует избегать по возможности.

Answer (score 0):

Если без цикла совсем никак не обойтись, то можно использовать курсор:

```
DECLARE @UserID int

DECLARE user_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT UserID FROM Users

OPEN user_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM user_cursor
INTO @UserID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- сделать что-то с текущим @UserID


    FETCH NEXT FROM user_cursor
    INTO @UserID
END 

CLOSE user_cursor;
DEALLOCATE user_cursor;
```